# How do I scale a row of images to fit container width?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a grid of images that will scale automatically to fit the available width. The number of images per row is arbitrary and the available width can vary as the user re-sizes the window. The original images also may be of different widths but need to be displayed with the same width each. I'd prefer to avoid tables and need a **CSS-only** solution. The html I envisage is something like:

```
<div class='img-grid'>  <!-- one per page, typically fixed 70% of page width -->
  <!-- can be an arbitrary number of rows per grid -->
  <div class='row'>  <!-- width would be 100% of img-grid width -->
    <!-- can be an arbitrary number of images per row -->
    <div class='img-wrapper'>  <!-- wrapper needs to force images to same width -->
      <img class='image' src="test1.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Seems simple but I'm getting confused with what css to use on each of the 4 classes to force the images to the same width, to scale that width so that the (arbitrary number of) images fit within the row without wrapping and to ensure everything re-scales as the browser window width changes.

Thanks
Nigel

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like bootstrap or zurb?

Comment: No I'm not, just plain vanilla html and CSS.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with CSS table layout, see the demo follows.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhqushp2/)**</kbd>

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x200/bbb" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox is usefull in your scenario:

Add `display:flex` to the row:
And `flex: 1` to the row items:

```css
.img-grid { width: 70%; }
.row { width: 100%; display: flex; }
img { width: 100%;  }
.img-wrapper
{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-grid'>  <!-- one per page, typically fixed 70% of page width -->
  <!-- can be an arbitrary number of rows per grid -->
  <div class='row'>  <!-- width would be 100% of img-grid width -->
    <!-- can be an arbitrary number of images per row -->
    <div class='img-wrapper'>
      <img class='image' src="http://placeimg.com/440/680/any"/>
    </div>
    <div class='img-wrapper'>
      <img class='image' src="http://placeimg.com/640/380/any"/>
    </div>
    <div class='img-wrapper'>
      <img class='image' src="http://placeimg.com/540/480/any"/>
    </div>
    <div class='img-wrapper'>
      <img class='image' src="http://placeimg.com/640/280/any"/>
    </div>
    <div class='img-wrapper'>
      <img class='image' src="http://placeimg.com/740/480/any"/>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex works really well but any ideas for how to support earlier browsers (e.g. IE9).

Comment: For IE8-9 you could go with `display:table-cell` for `.img-wrapper`, it's not as perfect as the flexbox but do a fair work

Answer (score -1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/u471prst/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.img-grid {
  width: 70%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.img-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-grid'>
  <!-- one per page, typically fixed 70% of page width -->
  <!-- can be an arbitrary number of rows per grid -->
  <div class='row'>
    <!-- width would be 100% of img-grid width -->
    <!-- can be an arbitrary number of images per row -->
    <div class='img-wrapper'>
      <!-- wrapper needs to force images to same width -->
      <img class='image' src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/any" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. However, if there are multiple large images per row these wrap, instead of scaling to fit on one row. I'm looking to have the images exactly fit across the row, whatever their original width.